# Oracle is not inserting a value correctly

Tags: oracle

I am having the strangest experience with Oracle, and hopefully someone more knowledge able can help me out.  I am writing a stored procedure that generates and honor roll name for a school.  The exact format of the honor roll name is being generated by a function (and the function is working properly).  The procedure gives the entity a new record in a table called NAME for someone without an honor roll name, and then it will update someone's honor roll name if the function generates one that's different from the old one (to account for updates on other tables).

The procedure also generates audit info in another table and is scheduled to run at night.  When I check the logs (which is in test environment), it says X rows were inserted and Y rows were update.  However, the expectation is 0 rows updated because no one has an honor roll name.

So getting to the relevant stuff, below is simplified code that I am using. Let's saying the function should return 'John '69 & Jane Jones '70 Smith'

```
insert into NAME
select ID_NUMBER,
NAME_FUNCTION(ID_NUMBER)
from ENTITY
```

after this the update runs

```
update NAME
set TENTCARD_NAME = NAME_FUNCTION(ID_NUMBER)
where TENTCARD_NAME != NAME_FUNCTION(ID_NUMBER)
```

So the problem is the insert is putting the value 'John '69 & Jane '70 Smith' (dropping the maiden name) in the insert query.  Keep in mind the function works perfect if you do select NAME_FUNCTION(ID_NUMBER) from dual.  Moreover, if you separate the select clause from the insert clause, it will return the correct value.

Where the plot thickens is that one would expect that because it inserted wrong, the update will fix it.  Nope!  The update will update 0 rows, even though my audit query says it should update 160.

If I just run the update statement and look at an affected entity from the front end client, the wrong value shows up.

Any thoughts and/or suggestions would be super helpful at this point!

EDIT:  Here is the simplest test cast I can write

```
insert into name (id_number, tentcard_name, date_added)
select e.id_number,
bu_hrdnames(e.id_number,'N','N','Y','Y','Y') as tentcard_name,
sysdate as date_added
from entity e
where e.id_number = '0000001034'
```

This inserts the value 'Robert '69 MBA '73 & Kathryn '70 Andersen'
When it should be inserting 'Robert '69 MBA '73 & Kathryn Wilson '70 Andersen'.  Which it does if I just do this query:

```
select e.id_number,
bu_hrdnames(e.id_number,'N','N','Y','Y','Y') as tentcard_name,
sysdate as date_added
from entity e
where e.id_number = '0000001034'
```

Comment: which version of Oracle are you on?

Comment: 11g.  But I am using TOAD 10.6.1.3 as the DBMS.

Comment: Can you please provide results of:  `desc name` and `desc name_function` and `desc entity`  please ? would help to understand what we're working with ;)

Comment: In the insert - select statement, list the columns in your insert by name. `insert into NAME (col1, col2) select ...`.  In your update statement, check for null in your where clause. `where nvl(TENTCARD_NAME,'-') != nvl(NAME_FUNCTION(ID_NUMBER),'-')

Comment: "If I just run the update statement and look at an affected entity from the front end client, the wrong value shows up."

Are you doing a commit after the updates in the SQL window of TOAD, then requerying the data grid window?

Comment: Ditto-  These things are pretty large.  I don't know if a forum would be a great place to post them.  The name function is like 360 lines of code.

Comment: @jacob: Then re-create a smaller test case in your DEV environment, with just the 1 or 2 columns related to the issue. often rebuilding this test scenario, you find your problem ;)  If you still don't, post that complete test case, so we can help better.  We're kind of running blind, and "guessing" (hence a lot of comments, and no "answers") ;)

Comment: I agree with PeterM: this sounds like a missing commit. And add your "audit query" that shows the wrong values

Comment: Commit statements are both in the code and the execution window.

Comment: Ditto-  I understand what you are saying, and I am not opposed to posting more code.  I was hoping there was an easy explanation that didn't need more code.

Comment: So hang on, you do an insert of all rows from entity into the name table, and presumably `NAME_FUNCTION(ID_NUMBER)` goes into the TENTCARD_NAME column? If so, why do you think you would then have rows where the TENTCARD_NAME would need to be updated?

Comment: The check for null that I mentioned in my first comment is important. Because at the moment, if TENTCARD_NAME is null after the insert, it will never pick up those rows for update of the name.

Comment: Boneist- The short answer is that we're not inserting for every entity in the entity table.  And we need to check to see if ones that were inserted previously need to be update due to getting married or whatever.

Comment: I have also tried listing all of the columns that will be inserted into, and that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @jacob: you're going to need to create a smaller test case to isolate the problem.  Because of what you said here: "So the problem is the insert is putting the value 'John '69 & Jane '70 Smith' (dropping the maiden name) in the insert query"  I believe something's wrong with the logic inside your function .. it's not deterministic .. something's changing .. you'll need a COMPLETE - small test case for us to help more.

Comment: I just edited to and added more real code.

Comment: At this point you might want to make some basic edits to your code to recheck some assumptions. Is the function you expect to run actually running? Does it hit the table you expect it to hit? Is everything running on the instance you think it's running on? Just write junk strings instead of the formatted name and check that the row is changing in the place you expect it to change. Check the feedback from SQL for "1 row inserted", check the date_added to ensure it's right now etc. Don't forget to say "thanks for your interest in my question" once in a while to keep people engaged in it.